# scheduling an exe without windows task scheduler

Tags: c#, windows, task, scheduler

Is it possible to schedule an .exe file without using any task scheduler or sql scheduler?
What I want to do is that I am having a file in C# and it is to be executed independently but without any task scheduler or sql scheduler.
The reason behind this is security issues.

Comment: If you could elaborate on what you mean by "schedule" and "security issues" it'd be very helpful. If you don't want the supported, surefire, failsafe way of Windows Task Scheduler, you'll have to create and install your own task scheduling service that does exactly the same as the existing solutions. This is not trivial to get right, and too broad to answer anyway.

Comment: tbh, I'm fairly sure that implementing your own version of task scheduler would be less secure and cause you more issues...

Comment: Yes, you need to elaborate on these "security issues" for two reasons - one is that we don't know whether anything else we suggest might fall foul of these same "security issues". The other is that you may have a misunderstanding of something but until we know what you're thinking of, we've no ability to spot that and help to correct you.

Comment: I'm always torn on these - my instinct is to assume that the requirements listed aren't accurate. Then again I've been on the other side of this where I've been going down the rabbit hole for weeks on a problem and ruled out all the obvious approaches because of subtle issues that took ages to tease out. Sometimes it is just too much to rehash and if you go into that much detail in the question people ignore it and post the obvious solution anyways. Not saying it is the case - just that sometimes it is reasonable to ask for an answer without the whole backstory.

Comment: @Kelly the question in and of itself is _"If I can't use existing scheduler infrastructure, how can I 'schedule' an executable?"_ (without explaining how they want to schedule exactly). That question is unclear, too broad and duplicate altogether, and the answer is: either roll your own scheduler or put it in the "run" registry, and that has been answered before. Both approaches have massive drawbacks and require feedback from OP to determine whether they are viable. That's why OP needs to specify more what they are looking for.

Comment: @KellyGendron - if you're ruling out the *most obvious* solution to a problem, you need to give at least some explanation beyond "it's not right" or, as here "security reasons". I can't even picture what "security reasons" might be, at this stage, other than "it'll be obvious my code is going to run, i.e. I'm writing malware". It's not like there's a limit to the length of a question here. People can structure it into as many layers/depth of information as they like, so the question itself is right at the top but failed attempts are also covered.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can create the scheduler in your own C# app.

1. Build your app as a console app
2. Wraps your logic into custom scheduler like this.

   ```
    public class Schedule : ISchedule
   {
       readonly List<Timer> timers = new List<Timer>();

       public Schedule()
       {
       }

       public Timer Every(TimeSpan interval, Action action)
       {
           var timer = new Timer(_ => action(), null, new TimeSpan(), interval);
           timers.Add(timer);
           return timer;
       }

       public void Stop(Timer timer)
       {
           if (timer != null && timers.Contains(timer))
           {
               timer.Dispose();
               timers.Remove(timer);
           }
       }
   }

   public class MyMainClass
   {
      void Main(){
         var processor = new MyProcessor();    

         ISchedule scheduler = new Schedule();
         schedule.Every(TimeSpan.FromDays(1), processor.Run)
      }
   }

   public class MyProcessor
   {
      void Run(){
       //do more here
      }
    }
   ```
3. Install the app as windows service using [Topshelf][1]

   [1]: https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf. Topshelf allows you to create a console app and install/host it as windows service via simple commands.

Comment: While it is _an_ option, implementing your own scheduler is not trivial. The code you show will not handle failures, service restarts nor feedback.

Comment: hmm true, there's some complexity still. service restart and failures can be covered by service recovery options of Topshelf.

Comment: TopShelf will manage to get your executable running again after a failure, but that will not continue or restart tasks by itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can always deploy your executable anywhere and create a startup entry in the registry, here:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376977(v=vs.85).aspx)

This way, your executable will start when Windows starts and you can programatically set the time when your task should be executed.

Comment: This is _an_ option, but assumes two things: there is a user logging on before the application needs to be started, and the user that will log on has the proper permissions to run and use the app. It also has zero error handling, so if your app fails to start, you won't notice it.

Comment: Since task scheduler is not an option, there's not much left. And to avoid crashing, you should always put an exception handler there. This registry key can be used without admin privileges.

Comment: just because you *can* doesn't mean you *should*. the OP's requirements are misguided and probably harmful.

Comment: Yeah I'm not saying this is _not_ an option, but it does have its drawbacks.

Comment: It's the best approach considering that scheduled tasks are not possible and since there's absolutely no explenation why, I think this is a pretty good solution. If you don't think so, feel free to post your's.

Answer (score 0):

As other poster have mentioned it is probably prudent to at least give the standard task-scheduler route another look as I can't think of any security advantages to avoiding it - then again I don't know your scenario.

I did have a project where I needed to do something similar though - The system needed to run tasks added by users - the tasks where either to be run ASAP, at a given time, or at a given interval.

I set it up as a windows service that was set to run on startup. The service simply waited an interval (usually about a minute) then checked the database for any tasks scheduled to run between the last tick and the current. The tasks were maintained in a SQL database. It wasn't trivial to write but seemed to be reliable once implemented.

A few considerations-
Timing will not be exact
Error handling is critical - ensure that individual tasks can't take down the process
Be careful to handle edge cases appropriately so you don't end up dropping tasks between ticks

Again though I would be careful of ruling out the task scheduler route prematurely.